# How to Use If else in Neo4j Cypher or using RNeo4j?

Tags: r, neo4j, cypher, r-neo4j

My Neo4j Database has 5 different types of nodes and total 120k nodes.
There are very few cases where all 5 types of node are connected through relationships.

For example, (A)-->(B)-->(C)-->(D)-->(E).
In that case I want to return this path of 4 length depending on id search, else return any path of 4 that exist else any path of 3 so on.

Currently, I am sending 5 path cypher, 4 path cypher, so on from R program to Neo4j, which is expensive.

**Is there any easiest way to do this in single Cypher.**?

There are many question discussion similar to this which suggest use of CASES, FOR EACH, APOC. But nothing seems to work for me

Comment: What you mean `depending on id search`? What about example?

Comment: All these types represented by labels? And if so does the order matter? Could we interpret your pattern as a path with nodes of those labels in that specific order, or does the order of the labeled/type nodes not matter?

Comment: @stdob-- I mean search based on ID property of any label. For Example,  suppose user input ID property of Node A, then search if any pattern exists.
 Order doesn't matter. All types are represented by labels.